# "There wasn't among X a more beautiful creature"

Tags: meaning, grammar, sentence

I'm having trouble constructing a sentence. Which sounds more natural (and which is plainly wrong):

1) There wasn’t among angels, humans, gods, or any species a creature more beautiful than her.

2) There was neither among angels, humans, gods, or any species a creature more beautiful than her.

I think both are grammatically correct, but I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The second needs another negative sentence before it to license it. I'd expect 'she' rather than 'her', the writing style is so old. But they're unidiomatic  nowadays.

Comment: "There" is not literarily striking. No angel, human, god or animal was more beautiful than she.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, the problem with the specific construction in the example sentence is the lack of the definite article:

> ✘ I am the tallest in group.
>   ✔ I am the tallest in **the** group.

So, idiomatically, I'm far more used to hearing something like this:

> There wasn't among **the** angels, humans, gods, or any species a creature more beautiful than her.

The article is necessary because you're talking about a specific group of beings.

---

Less significant is that the use of *any species* in the list causes a slight break in parallelism. Although the addition of the definite article in front of the list helps it sound idiomatic at an overall level, a further tweak (while not nearly as obvious) would also help:

> There wasn't among the angels, humans, gods, or any **other** species a creature more beautiful than her.

Without using *other*, all of the list items that precede *any species* become redundant. If it really is *any species*, then enumerating some specific ones in such a construction is not needed when you could just say this:

> There wasn't among any species a creature more beautiful than her.

---

Combining those two things we end up with this:

> There wasn't among the angels, humans, gods, or any other species a creature more beautiful than her.